# How can an User model both belong_to and Has_many of another model depending if the user is an Admin or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

Im trying to create some Active Record associations to model an agricultural Farm, so far i have and user model with and admin boolean field, which  means that some users are admin and other are not. I also have a farm model.

Now if a user if and admin User it has_many farms, but if a user is not an admin user it belong_to a farm (employee). So basically my question is how can an User belong_to or has_many depending on its admin status? or which is the proper way to model this relationship , do i have to create a different model for Admins?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to my like your model has actually two different kind of associations. One that defines ownership and one that defines where a user works:

```
belongs_to :farm_employed_at, class_name: "Farm"
has_many   :owned_farms,      class_name: "Farm"
```

You can then add validations to ensure that only the right type of association is set:

```
validates :farm_association

private
def farm_assosiation
  if admin?
    errors.add(:base, "Admins should not work")            if farm_employed_at
  else
    errors.add(:base, "Users aren't allowed to own farms") if owned_farms.any?
  end
end
```